# Why is $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

After reading chapter 1 of Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis, I started working on the exercises. Exercise 6 was a big surprise since exercises 1-5 had all been very simple, whereas 6 had me stumped for a ver long time until I read solutions online. The problem is:

For integers $m,n,p,q$ let $r=m/n=p/q$, prove that for positive $b$
$$(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$$
Then show that for rationals $r,s$
$$b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$$
If $$b^x=\sup \{ b^t : t\le x,t\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
Show that for reals $x,y$
$$b^{x+y}=b^xb^y$$
After reading the solutions I think I could have solved the first and second parts of the question, but for the last part, the solution made use of several propositions, corollaries and had to prove a lemma before starting the demonstration. 

This made me a little suspicious, since exercise 7 asked for the proof of several of these facts. So I was wondering if there are alternate proofs, and if there are, what is the simplest you know?

[This is the link to the solutions I am talking about](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1220964.files/sol2.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiOz9WW-J3RAhVn64MKHaQQAoMQFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNH1Gie0-ibYdIJJBWoNyz4iSf_XkQ)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Revenge, I'm guessing.

Comment: @user361424 revenge for what?

Comment: The result for x and y real is something one could prove fully rigorously in a million ways, none of them fun. The key facts are that the rationals are dense in the reals and that for arbitrarily close rationals q and q', $b^{q}$ is arbitrarily close to $b^{q'}.$ Thus the result for real numbers can be approximated by the result on rationals. Since x + y is close to qx + qy for rationals qx and qy approximating x and y, the equation must still hold for the reals. I don't think the labors of a fully rigorous proof are as important as the intuition here, but could be good practice.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Although it takes up a lot of space, the argument is not particularly complex or even long. I think it's presented in a misleadingly way. The lemma evoked is extremely straightforward and admits a much simpler proof:

$$r < \frac{r+(x+y)}{2} = \frac{2x+r}{4}+\frac{2y+r}{4} < x + y$$

Now to finish the problem you can just iteratively apply this to obtain a monotonic sequence of rationals that approach $x+y$ from bellow, and take a sup, as the function $f(x)=k^x$ is monotonic and order preserving.

Comment: What are the dyadics?

Comment: @user143646 the set rational numbers with denominators that are powers of 2.

Comment: @user143646 however, the density of the diadics is not actually the key factor. I rephrased the ending. There is a slightly different proof that depends on the density of the diadics, where we use that fact to get our sequence instead of this lemma.